# What is the difference between mida k'negged mida and nekama

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, reward-punishment, chinuch-education, revenge-nekama

Not a kasha, a sincere question. What is the exact reason that mida k'negged mida is not considered revenge?

Issues that may or may not be relevant:

- Is it just because it is Hashem doing it?
- Does revenge include a "emotional" component that makes it forbidden?
- Are we allowed to do mida kneged mida in our courts?
- With our children for chinuch?
- With our friends to help them realise what is wrong with their behaviour?

Comment: Are you assuming it's not because revenge is bad? What about אל נקמות השם?

Comment: @MichoelR good point, maybe they are the same. That would be an interesting answer. Still not sure. I'll update the question at some point

Comment: What about the concept of punishment in general? Isn’t that revenge? Obviously not since it’s for our ultimate good. Midah keneged midah is just a way of punishment so the person knows why he’s getting punished

Comment: @Chatzkel So perhaps you are saying that they are the same, but mida k'negged mida is ok because it is for our good (and done by Hashem who is capable of doing something for someone else's good unambiguously)?

Comment: I forget where, somewhere Rashi _defines_ נקמה as גמול.

Comment: I think נקמה is generally forbidden because it distances people instead of bringing them together, and you don't want that between two Jews. But the idea of compensation is not a bad one in theory, you just gotta do it right. Don't throw anything at me, but my Rebbi a"h understood that what Yosef did to his brothers in coming parshiyos was an example of a permissible נקמה: He took steps (that did cause his brothers some pain) that had the end goal of fixing what they had broken between them. I found that fascinating.

Comment: @MichoelR this would be a wonderful answer, if written up in full. Shabbat shalom

Comment: Shabbat shalom; not sure I can. Unfortunately I can no longer ask my Rebbi for more details. I'll think about it, though.

Comment: And is a goel hadam doing an act of nekama or midda kneged midda? Related question here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130499/how-can-not-taking-revenge-be-reconciled-with-the-concept-of-goel-hadam

Answer (score 0):

Revenge is when you are responding to something bad having been done to you, and you as the victim, by getting back at the aggressor, will feel right again by having levelled the negative charges.

Judgement is when you set out to fix society, by either getting rid of the bad apples or setting strong examples. Hashem is obviously not affected by our actions and all His responses are Judgements.

Now, as for actual revenge, the [Gemara in Yoma 23](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.23a.1?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he) does imply that Nekama is only an issue when done with money. Scaring a person off, or even a witty or sharp retort ([as in Beitza 20b](https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.20b.3?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he)) is not included.

Moreover, it seems that in most instances the pain being inflicted is for the purpose of alerting the person to look in to his actions and correct whatever needs to be corrected, as it says in [Brachos 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.5a.9?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he): If a person sees that suffering has befallen him, he should examine his actions.

The idea of Midah Kneged Modah is to point out why it is happening.

Comment: So 1. revenge has an emotional component, which is the issue. 2 revenge can't apply to Hashem because He is above that negative emotion (and monetary matters), and He is judging us when He does mkm, for the good. So they are not the same because of the emotional component? Are we always at risk of this emotional component or are we sometimes able to also perform mkm in a way that is not considered nekama? What are your sources for your first sentence btw? I have to admit I haven't looked at MT or Sefer Hachinuch on this yet

Comment: If the idea of mkm is waking someone up to bad behaviour, that's something that would be very helpful for us to do too, at times