# Hashem over the lav of not bearing a grudge

Tags: rashi, ezekiel--the-book

Hashem says in Yechezkel 16:59 "For so said the Lord God: I have done with you as you did, that you despised an oath to violate a covenant," to which Rashi comments, "that you despised an oath, etc.: That one that you accepted upon yourself in Horeb (Deut. 29: 11): “That you pass into the covenant of the Lord your God, etc.” But I shall not violate the covenant by not remembering it, because I am not like you."  Seems like this is a classic case of bearing a grudge with Hashem saying "I won't do like you did because I'm not like you."  Is Hashem in fact oyver this lav, and if so, is it the case that Hashem isn't mechuyav in the Taryag mitzvos as his creations are?

Comment: It is uniquely appropriate for HaShem, unlike people, to deal with His creations measure for measure ("מדה כנגד מדה") when He sees fit (see, for e.g., [Deut. 32:35](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0532.htm#35)). There are many instances of this throughout Tanach, as well as many instances of HaShem's compassion and patience. Humans, on the other hand, are myopic and often driven by ego and self-interest. Without the restraint of "לֹא תִקֹּם וְלֹא תִטֹּר", human nature unbridled would result in a chaotic society governed more by *lex vindictae* than by *lex talionis*.

Comment: @Fred do any meforshim address the fact that Hashem is doing what he expressly forbade Jews to do in holding a grudge?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if somebody addressed it from that angle, but fundamentally it's not a question to begin with. The prohibition expressly applies to one's peers ("בְּנֵי עַמֶּךָ"), and HaShem, infinite and omniscient as He is, is categorically above us capricious and limited beings who require the restraint of "Do not take revenge! Do not bear a grudge!" in our dealings with our fellows.

Comment: @Fred yeah but i'm looking for meforshim not opinions.

Comment: Very well. Consider editing that into your question. You should also edit in the basis for your assumption that HaShem is "obligated" to "observe" the commandments.

Comment: @Fred we would expect Hashem to at least observe the ethical bein adam l'chaveiro commandments such as not to bear a grudge

Comment: `to at least observe the ethical bein adam l'chaveiro commandments` Why? If there is some reason why you think this, please include it in your question.

Comment: @Fred it's a sevara.  If someone commands you to do something, we would expect that person to practice what he preaches.

Comment: So if a police officer commands you not to touch his gear, should he also practice what he preaches and not touch his own gear? If a kohen tells a Yisrael not to do the 'avoda in the Beis HaMikdash, should he practice what he preaches?

Comment: @Fred that's an incorrect analogy.  Hashem commanded us to emulate Him.  Hashem holds grudges, but he commands us not to hold grudges.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you are asking how to reconcile our responsibility to emulate HaShem's *middos* (*Shabbos* 133b, "מה הוא חנון ורחום") and conduct (*Sotah* 14a, "אלא להלך אחר מדותיו של הקב"ה מה הוא מלביש ערומים") with various instances of *middos* or conduct we should not emulate. I recommend you edit that into your question for clarification.

Comment: @Fred incorrect.  my question was clear.

Comment: @Fred could you have a look at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132198/what-is-the-difference-between-mida-knegged-mida-and-nekama, it sounds like what you are saying here is highly relevant

Comment: @RabbiKaii i'm looking for anything actual meforshim say on this, not wild speculation